# JSFiddle How to get script to load first?

Tags: javascript, parsing, sequence, jsfiddle

If run my code as is (https://jsfiddle.net/Natronox/fhbm3gdq/#&togetherjs=Re8lLHwJMd) I cannot click to get a random image... ie code doesn't work. However if I put the JS in a script tag in the body frame first, it works. How can I do this while still keeping the JS in the correct frame?

```
var games = ["http://cdn.ndtv.com/tech/gadgets/06_hitman.jpg",
  "http://img.wallpaperfolder.com/f/6203714F2BE7/deus-ex-1920x1200-412032.jpg",
  "http://warnerbros.edelmandigital.us/tumblr/img/header-hero-bg.jpg"
];

function imageChanger(that) {
  var imageNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

  while (that.src.indexOf(games[imageNumber]) != -1) {
imageNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
  }
  that.src = games[imageNumber];
  return false;
};
```

Comment: You change the JS settings from *"onload"* to *"no wrap in `<body>`"*.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fhbm3gdq/2/

Comment: To change the JS settings, click the gear next to the word "JavaScript"